# How to run a jar residing in another jar from command prompt

Tags: java

I have B.jar which resides in A.jar. I want to run B.jar from command prompt. How to do that?

Comment: You need a custom class loader.  I would suggest another approach

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can unless you unzip A.jar first:

1. Unzip A.jar
2. java -jar B.jar